# how to resolve git remote end hung up unexpectedly

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

I'm trying to push my repo to bitbucket on windows using ssh, but I got this error after I run

`git push -u origin --all` I got this error

> Read from remote host bitbucket.org: Connection reset by peer
>
> fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
>
> fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

and I've did some search and set buffer like

`http.postbuffer=52428800000`

but it didn't work.

I've successfully generate the public key and log in using `SSH -T git@bitbucket.org`

is there anything I did wrong or missed?  and how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

it seems that there is something wrong with my http.postbuffer setting, I've set it globally, and somehow it doesn't apply locally, after I set it without `--global` argument and the problem is solved.